# How to use different application.conf in play commandline?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

`play -Dconfig.file=conf/dev.conf` not work, How to use different application.conf in play commandline?

play-2.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Dconfig.file` requires full path to the file which is **not** packaged into distribution i.e.:
`/home/sato/app-configs/dev.conf`

In your case you should use rather: `-Dconfig.resource=dev.conf` to use additional config stored in `conf` folder.

- [See descriptions in the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ProductionConfiguration)

Comment: I tried, but play still uses `application.conf` instead of `dev.conf`, and it got error if I move `application.conf`.